# Define based on detected library version

Tags: c, waf

How can I check for a library version, and if it is below a certain version (i.e. missing feature X) set a define ?

Currently I have this code, which checks for libsoup and its version. It seems to work.

```
conf.check_cfg(package='libsoup-2.4', mandatory=True)
conf.check_cfg(package='libsoup-2.4', uselib_store='SOUP', msg='Checking for \'libsoup\' < 2.40', args=['libsoup-2.4 < 2.40', '--cflags', '--libs'], mandatory=False, define_variable={'OLD_SOUP':1,'FRESH_SOUP':0})
conf.check_cfg(package='libsoup-2.4', uselib_store='SOUP', msg='Checking for \'libsoup\' >= 2.40', args=['libsoup-2.4 >= 2.40', '--cflags', '--libs'], mandatory=False, define_variable={'OLD_SOUP':0,'FRESH_SOUP':1})
```

Is there anything simpler and shorter to do the same job, i.e. with `check_cc`?

Comment: `pkg-config --modversion package`

Comment: It is suppposed to be C code, so why aren't there any `;` ? Is it autoconf code ?

Comment: @David RF a full sentence would be appreciated, but you got me going in the right direction

Comment: @Mathuin it is python/waf code, which I use to compile my C projects - waf has the capability to build projects based on various languages and libraries, therefore the C tag

Comment: Ok, sorry for the dumbass question ... I thought waf was a library. Facepalm all you want ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with this, I simply overlooked one of `check_cfg`'s many options

```
ctx.check_cfg(package='libsoup-2.4', uselib_store='SOUP', args=['--cflags', '--libs'], mandatory=True)
ctx.define ('FRESH_SOUP', (ctx.check_cfg(modversion='libsoup-2.4') >= '2.40'))
```

http://waf.googlecode.com/svn/docs/apidocs/tools/c_config.html#waflib.Tools.c_config.check_cfg